# PHPStorm Live Edit for php or an alternative (for firefox)

Tags: php, firefox, phpstorm

PHPStorm has a nice little plugin called "Live Edit", however it works only for javascript, html, etc. Exept for php...

My question would be simple - is there any way to make it work for php on firefox? I already have local MySQL and Apache server running. Documentation say no, but who knows?

Comment: It works for PHP for me...

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me on Chrome, but the main idea of this Jeopardy question was to make it work on Firefox. I guess I'll have to edit my post.

Comment: Live Edit does NOT work with Firefox -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1805

Comment: P.S. (unrelated to the actual problem) I'm ignoring the fact that such detailed answer was typed in less than 40 seconds (your are not the first who answer own questions almost immediately)

Comment: Well, I clearly stated that Live Edit doesn't work for Firefox according to documentation and I see you didn't get my reference to Jeopardy... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Somehow I've missed that question was specifically about Firefox (temp blindness, I guess; but now, after edit, it's easier to notice "firefox" there). As for "Jeopardy" -- did not know that.

Answer (score 3):

Just as I posted my question, I found an answer myself (happens constantly). Instead of using Live Edit I found quite a nice alternative (and on firefox too!).

What you need is ["Auto Reload"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-reload/), a firefox plugin, which detects file changes and reloads page.

Here's a little guide (assuming that you have PHPStorm and XAMMP configured):

1. Open plugin's settings.
2. Create new rule.
3. For Url type: `http://localhost/<MyPage>/*`
4. For files, add file or select directory: `C:\xampp\htdocs\<MyPage>`
5. Make sure autosych is enabled between PHPStorm and local server.
6. Click `Open in Browser '*.php' on XAMMP Apache`
7. Edit code and see results.

Comment: Link is broken, and all the extensions I found reload after a time period (refreshing while changes are detected seems way better to me). Do you still use a good alternative ?